# Apache Spark 1.6.0, callUDF is failing

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am struggling with callUDF functionality, I am always getting the error that function is not registered. I have pasted the sample code below:

```java
UDF1<String, String> func = new UDF1<String, String>(){
      public String call(String s) throws Exception {
            return s +"fixedString";
  }
};
sqlContext.udf().register("test",func, DataTypes.StringType);
out = out.select(out.col("VERSION"),callUDF("test",out.col("STEP_EXECUTION_ID")) );
```

I am always getting the following error, what is missing from the code.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: undefined function test;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleFunctionRegistry$$anonfun$2.apply(FunctionRegistry.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleFunctionRegistry$$anonfun$2.apply(FunctionRegistry.scala:65)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleFunctionRegistry.lookupFunction(FunctionRegistry.scala:64)
```

Comment: The error is org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: undefined function test;

Comment: Then you better edit your question to improve readability.

Comment: Never mind. I just did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved that issue so posting it here if others are facing similar issues. I had two problems, 1. Generating a UUID in one column 2. Generating calculated values from a column value.

Problem 1:

```
import java.util.UUID;

public class RandomGenerator extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0<String> {
    public String apply() {
       return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
```

In this case no need to register this with `sqlcontext`

```
df.withColumn("UUID", callUDF(new RandomGenerator(), DataTypes.StringType)).show();
```

Problem 2:

In this case above approach can be used or someone can do the following as well

```
UDF1< Integer, Integer> func = new UDF1<Integer, Integer>() {
    public Integer call(Integer s) throws Exception {
        return calculate(s);
    }
};

sqlContext.udf().register("calculate", func, DataTypes.IntegerType);
df.select(df.col("calVal"), callUDF("calculate", df.col("value"))).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code it seems that the function test cannot be found because the Scala code is trying to do reflection and find a function called test that accepts a long or whatever type you are using as ID on the STEP_EXECUTION_ID column.

Try to change the argument type of your UDF to match the column type. Something like this:

`public String call(Long id) throws Exception`

Comment: I tried with a column which was of String type and the error is still the same

Comment: It is possible then that you are registering the UDF where out cannot see. Try to debug while having a checkpoint on FunctionRegistry.scala  to see the visible content of the UDF registry.

Comment: Function is also registered     sqlContext.functionRegistry().lookupFunction("xyz").isDefined() returns true

Comment: Oh, my bad. I guess you need to specify the argument type. You are using this method: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#callUDF%28scala.Function0,%20org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType%29 instead of this method: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#callUDF%28java.lang.String,%20scala.collection.Seq%29

Comment: The second URL above provides a simple example.

Comment: Thanks for the help, issue was data type

Comment: @HarvinderSingh Can you elaborate a little more? So that in the future someone with the same question can solve the problem.